# Can't login after logout using AccountsTemplates

Tags: meteor, meteor-useraccounts

I have the following configuration for useraccounts:

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
  defaultLayout: 'baseLayout',
  defaultLayoutRegions: {},
  defaultContentRegion: 'content',
  defaultState: 'signUp',
  confirmPassword: false,
  onLogoutHook: function () {
    FlowRouter.go('atSignIn');
  },
});
```

And this is my flow route for handling logout:

```
FlowRouter.route('/logout', {
  action: AccountsTemplates.logout
});
```

The problem is that, whenever I log out I get redirected to the sign in view (as expected) but I won't be able to login again: when I enter the right credentials no errors are shown but the form won't dissapear. Any idea?

**UPDATE**

Replacing the logout function with Meteor's own as shown below would cause a redirection loop between sign-in and logout.

```
FlowRouter.route('/logout', {
  action: function () {
    Meteor.logout(function () {
      FlowRouter.go('atSignIn');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: have you tried `Meteor.logout();` inside the enter trigger of that route?

Comment: Hi @sdybskiy, I've updated my question based on your comment, thanks